# Android: Get the name of the camera (front, back, external)

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to find a way to tell me which camera(s) a device has.  I have the number of cameras, but I'd like to be able to know exactly which cameras they are.

My tablet currently has a front and back camera and I'd like to connect an external camera.  I have options that will allow the user to choose front back or external, assuming the device has all 3.  If the device only has a rear camera, I will only want to show that as an "option".  Or if it has only front and back, or front and external, etc.

I have this so far:

```
CameraManager myCamera = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
final int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
Toast.makeText(StartPage.this, numCameras + " cameras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
for(int i = 0; i <= numCameras; i++){
    Log.d("cameraNum", "Camera "+i)
    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
}
```

So, I have the number of cameras, I toast the number (showing 2, I still have to figure out how to show 3 with the external camera connected) and I start a for loop starting at zero.

But I don't know how to do use the last two lines to tell me which camera I have available.  How do I use the variable `cameraInfo` to tell me if it's front, back or external?

Comment: did you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

> How do I use the variable cameraInfo to tell me if it's front, back or external?

`Camera.CameraInfo` has [a `facing` field](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#facing). Quoting the JavaDocs, it is:

> The direction that the camera faces. It should be `CAMERA_FACING_BACK` or `CAMERA_FACING_FRONT`.

There is no support in `Camera` for external cameras. I do not know if the Android 5.0+ `android.hardware.camera2` API supports external cameras or not.

Comment: Ah great! Thank you!  Will accept when the time limit is reached

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_FACING Yes, the camera2 API supports 'external' as a 'lens facing'